# how to register a custom filter in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

in my spring-security.xml i have this

```
<custom-filter  before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="MyAuthFilter" />
```

My custom filter is:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
......
}
}
```

But on the startup i have an error : No bean named 'MyAuthFilter' available.

My web.xml :

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/webproject-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your `web.xml` context config location I guess, it needs to be defined once for `ContextLoaderListener`.

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/webproject-servlet.xml 
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml            
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: contextConfigLocation has been defined twice

Comment: But it's two different xml files. Should i compile them in one? It worked fine before i added custom filter.

Comment: yes. you can combine them, or declare it in a way as above

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

`<custom-filter  before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="MyAuthFilter" />` to

```
<custom-filter  before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />
```

OR

```
@Component
public class MyAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
```

to

```
@Component("MyAuthFilter")
public class MyAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
```